# AngularJS - ngRepeat inside a custom directive's transclusion is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am having troubles implementing a custom directive with `transclude: true` that can have a "transclusion" content that is using ngRepeat.

**[My case]**
I want to implement a set of directives, that are fetching the data that they are supposed to show from a $http service. For that I want to use preLink phase interceptor that Angular provides, so I can catch the data and set it to the scope. That way if I have some dynamic (since this term is well overloaded - I mean a data which structure is unknown until the request is done) data coming from the service, I rely on that, that I will be able to retrieve a list with that dynamic data and store it inside the scope, then loop through that data via ngRepeat inside the HTML. Here comes my problem...

**[My Problem]**
Angular is not using the list that I am assigning to the scope during preLink.

**[A plunkr]**
I maded a plunker that illustrated just the problem that I am having. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/XQOm4KWgKxRhn3pOWqzy?p=preview

**[My question]**
I really believe that such functionality is covered by angular and I am just missing something in the puzzle. 
Can anyone tell me how to implement such behaviour?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thank you **rchawdry** for your answer. Here are some details on my intentions. To make it simple I will try to give you an example.
Let's assume that we have these directives:
 1. *"page"* - This directive is a labeled container for all the page content. Visually it is represented as some div - for header, for content and for other fancy stuff if needed. The directive does not know what is its data before the page loads. As the page loads the directive must retrieve the information for itself and its children from a REST resourse! Then the directive is setting the information needed for itself (label and other stuff) and stores its children content in *childrenList* scope variable. It creates a scope. 
 2. *"section"* - This section can be child of *"page"*. Since *"page"* is retrieving its data from a server, then the information about how many *"section"*s does our *"page"* have is dynamic and we don't know how many *"section"*s we need to show on the screen. This depends on *sectionList* that is coming from the back-end. The section itself is almost the same as *"page"* - it is a labeled container, with the differences that - a). *"section"* is container of elements; b). *"section"* does retrieve its data from its parrent instead of making $http request. This directive creates a scope. 
 3. *"element"* - For this example, in order not to define many different elements and complicate it, let's assume that I have one element, called *"element"*. It can consist of some *"input"* with *"span"* and *"button"* if needed. It is similar to the *"section"* with that, that it retrieves the data to show from it's parrent (in the general case, this is *"section"* or *"page"*). On the other hand it is different than *"section"* by the fact that it has no transcluded content.

Now after we have some of the concept here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<page>
    <element id='element1' someOtherStuffHere...></element>
    <section id='static_section1' someOtherStuffHere...>
        <element id='element2' someOtherStuffHere...></element>
    </section>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="section in sections">
        <section dynamic_id='dynamic_section'>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="elem in elements">
                <element dynamic_id='dynamic_element'></element>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I believe that what your trying to achieve will be able by adding a `ng-repeat` attribute to the transcluded template.

by letting angular know about the 'repeat', it is supposed to work.

since plunkr is currently unavaliable, I can't prodivde any preview and do not have your original code. Ill try to recall it:

```
template: "<div id='container'>" + 
          "<div class='content' ng-repeat='item in [1]' ng-transclude'></div>" +
          "</div>"
```

edit: http://plnkr.co/edit/xba4pU666OGxBtKtcDwl?p=preview

Comment: I am not willing to use the local controller scope, just the opposite, I cannot afford my directives to have scope:false, because they can be included multiple times inside a template and if so - I will be in one hell of a trouble with the placeholders... As it is said in the angular documentation - if you are planning to make a reusable directive you will need to use either isolate scope or a new scope for your directive, messing with the controller is not an option...

Comment: I gave it a try for several hours to make it work like that, unfortunatelly this hack is not possile in my case :(. Thanks for posting in though!. So I am still looking for some more standard angular solution.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: I can try. I rely on the scope organization and in this case despite the fact that the ng-repeat inside the "content" div is loop with one step it created a scope, so is the ng-repeat from the transclusion. May be there is a way to reorganize my other code arround that idea, but I really believe that this standard problem have a standard angular solution. Believe me being more concrete with my problem will only make things more complicated and worse.

Comment: Im not sure I'm following you, but maybe changing the `scope:true` to `scope:{}` will get you any closer? (in addition to the hack)

Comment: Anyway let me know if you find a solid solution for that :)

Comment: have you tried changing the `scope:true` to `scope:{}` ?  just wondering... @MilenIgrachev

Comment: Yes I tried it is still not working that way. Both the statements are making the directive to create a scope, no matter if it is isolated or not.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a scope problem. The controller is using a variable that isn't defined in the controller (arrayListItemsPre and arrayListItemsPost).  While they are declared in the directives, accessing them in a transcluded scope is a little tricky.

The easy way is to do the following.  This will present the scope variables up to the controller where they can be used.

```
app.directive('container', function($compile) {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div class='container'>" +
                    "<div class='content' ng-transclude></div>" +
                      "</div>",

        compile: function(cElem, cAttrs) {

            return {
                pre : function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                    console.log("Hello from Container preLinkPhase");

                    scope.$parent.arrayListItemsPre = [1, 2];
                },
                post : function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                  scope.$parent.arrayListItemsPost = [1, 2];
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

There are other ways to do this that are better but it requires understanding why you're trying to iterate on variables that are defined in the directive. If you're going to be using this directive in another page that has different array elements, you'd have to change the directive code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working in the current case, however my real one is a bit messier. I made a try to give you more details I hope it is clear enough. I have one question. In your solution, by using $parent I am setting the list that I will itterate to to the controller outside of the directive (the <body> controller). Do I have to reach that <body> by using $parent...$parent to store my lists, or I just need to store them in the immediate $parent of the directive???

Comment: The way your directives are declared (scope:true), each directive gets its own scope, but also inherits properties from the parent so it can access these property elements.  In my example, by setting a property in the parent's scope, any child of the parent will have access to the variables.  So let's say you have another new directive in the body. That directive will be able to also access the variables set by the first directive (i.e in the pre or post link of the new directive, they can simply use "scope.arrayListItemsPre" (no need to indicate $parent because of prototypical inheritance)

Comment: That said, it's generally bad form to use $parent and use this as a way to exchange information because your directive's scope will change depending on usage.  This works fine above, but if you put ng-repeat in your `container`, you won't be setting scope variables in the body controller, it would be in the ng-repeat scope.  The other directives that were depending on values being set on the body, won't get them.  A better solution is to use isolate scopes and pass information explicitly between parent/child directives.

Comment: Setting ng-repeat in my container is not a solution, because that way I will only be able to duplicate only the entire transcluded content and as it is seen from the example, this is not the case. I will try to dig deeper into how I can implement isolate scope management, however I am sceptical that it will be possible. Thank you for the explanation and the propositions!